# CMD code for loop to arrange the file name If else Contain statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

This is my function in CMD batch. The purpose is to classify 9 folders according to different names for example if name contain 109 then the file will arrange to folder 109. However, I can only write 9 for loops here

(folder name is use the phone number 101-109 and the the format for file is date-phone1-phone2--record id 
some of record id will duplicate because the hunting line setting)

```
for /r %%i in (*) do ( 
If %%i contains '-101-' (move %%i 101)
else if %%i contains '-102-' (move %%i 102))
```

But that's not going to work. I also try  If %%i in (*-101-*) but also no work. Is there an easier way to write forloop to sort as it goes instead of asking for loop 9 times.

```
setlocal

set year=%date:~10,4%
set month=%date:~4,2%
set day=%date:~7,2%

cd C:\Users\SQ\Desktop\MWRecord
IF EXIST %year% (cd %year%) ELSE (mkdir %year% & cd %year%)
IF EXIST %year%%month% (cd %year%%month%) ELSE (mkdir %year%%month% & cd %year%%month%)
IF EXIST %year%%month%%day% (cd %year%%month%%day%) ELSE (cd ..\.. & move %year%%month%%day% %year%\%year%%month% & cd %year%\%year%%month%\%year%%month%%day%)

for /r %%i in (*-101-*) do ( IF EXIST 101 (move %%i 101) ELSE (mkdir 101 & move %%i 101))
for /r %%i in (*-102-*) do ( IF EXIST 102 (move %%i 102) ELSE (mkdir 102 & move %%i 102))
for /r %%i in (*-103-*) do ( IF EXIST 103 (move %%i 103) ELSE (mkdir 103 & move %%i 103))
for /r %%i in (*-104-*) do ( IF EXIST 104 (move %%i 104) ELSE (mkdir 104 & move %%i 104))
for /r %%i in (*-105-*) do ( IF EXIST 105 (move %%i 105) ELSE (mkdir 105 & move %%i 105))
for /r %%i in (*-106-*) do ( IF EXIST 106 (move %%i 106) ELSE (mkdir 106 & move %%i 106))
for /r %%i in (*-107-*) do ( IF EXIST 107 (move %%i 107) ELSE (mkdir 107 & move %%i 107))
for /r %%i in (*-108-*) do ( IF EXIST 108 (move %%i 108) ELSE (mkdir 108 & move %%i 108))
for /r %%i in (*-109-*) do ( IF EXIST 109 (move %%i 109) ELSE (mkdir 109 & move %%i 109))

endlocal
```

[image]

Comment: In the picture, the second file, it has both `-109-` and `-104-`, then which folder will you move it?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when a file has both numbers? See for instance example 2 and example 6 in your screenshot?

Comment: also, will the last digits before `.wav` always be a 3 digit number?

Comment: This is the voice record,Those 3-digit number 104 Numbers are for my own number, need to arrange to the following number folder, if own number call like example 2, thinking to use shorter than XXX statement to put the record to Other folder, but If unknown number called, the record also shorter, this problem is still thinking about the solution.

Comment: So you are saying that the number you actually are after is `*-109--nnn.wav` ?

Comment: the format for file is 
date-phone1-phone2--record id
same of record id will duplicate because the hunting line setting

Comment: ok, that is a problem, we need to only do it once then, you need to decide if you want phone 1 or phone 2, else it will become a tedious task.

Comment: I do not see a need or benefit in parsing todays date for this task, your files are each named according to their dates, so you should be parsing those first `8` characters for the creation of the directories instead. This would be a more sensible option because it would capture everything in cases where the script did not run every day or it ran before all of that days files had been created!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```bat
@echo off

for /L %%A IN (101 1 109) do (
    for /F "delims= eol=" %%B IN ('dir /S /B /A-D "*-%%A-*"') do (
        md "%%A" 2>nul
        move "%%~fB" "%%A"
    )
)
```

However, this won't fully work, if a file contains both `101` and `102` for example and you want to move it to `102` folder.

So, I would recommend the following, quite complicated code:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /A-D "*%%A*"') do (
    set "fname=%%~nA"
    set "all=!fname:--=-random-!"

    rem The code below is for the first phone:
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%C IN ("!all!") do (
        md "%%B"
        move "%%~fA" "%%~dpA%%~nxB"
    )
)
```

Replace `tokens=2` with `tokens=3` if you want the second phone.

Comment: thank a lot, I try this way and it is work, However, I still thinking the way let for loop will decide which folder it will send for every time the file scan, because if there are 100 files and 10 types, it needs to scan 1000 times instead of 100 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complete list of numbers (which seems to be the case) you want to search for, if that is the case, then perhaps this will help. It does not move the files, instead it will copy the file, so if you are looking for `104` it will copy it to folder `104` if however you search for both numbers as per second example in your list, being `104` and `109` it will copy the file to both folders `104` and `109` You could then simply do a `del *.wav` after both loops.

```
@echo off
set "list=101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108"
for %%i in (%list%) do (
  for /F %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "*-%%i-*"') do (
      mkdir %%i
      copy "%%a" %%i
    )
)
```

Comment: I may not be looking at this  correctly, but surely if the filename contains `-102-` and `-109-`, as in example `6`, this would make `\102\ `, copy the file to it, then delete it from the source. As it has been deleted it cannot now be parsed for copying to `\109\ `. Your copy and delete sequence has exactly the same function as a `move` would have  achieved!